# SSH to different machine to find the number of file

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, ssh

Here is my code:

```
echo "`${BOLD}`  ***** Checking CoreFile Creation *****`${UNBOLD}`"
    echo "========================================================"

    IFS='|'
        cat configMachineDetails.txt | grep -v "^#" | while read MachineType UserName MachineName
        do
        export CHK_COREFILE=`ssh -f -T ${UserName}@${MachineName} ls ~/corefiles | wc -l|sed 's/ //g'`
        if [ $CHK_COREFILE -gt 0 ]
        then    
            echo "CHK_COREFILE $CHK_COREFILE number of core files are created"
            echo "                    "     
            export CHK_COREFILES_NAME=`ls -lrt ~/corefiles`
            echo " Name of the Files $CHK_COREFILES_NAME "
            echo "MachineType $MachineType  UserName $UserName  MachineName $MachineName"

            echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
        fi
    done
```

After SSH to different machine it `ls` to the path of the machine on which the code is running. Hence it says the path not found.

```
export CHK_COREFILE=`ssh -f -T ${UserName}@${MachineName} ls ~/corefiles | wc -l|sed 's/ //g'`
```

How to handle this? Working on (ksh) Solaris.

Comment: It's not necessary to `export` the variables in the context you seem to be using them in.

Answer (score 1):

The `ssh` command that sets `CHK_COREFILE` only runs its own line on the remote server, which doesn't include `ls -lrt ~/corefiles`. The simple solution is to change the `CHK_COREFILES_NAME` assignment to

```
export CHK_COREFILES_NAME=`ssh -f -T ${UserName}@${MachineName} ls -lrt ~/corefiles`
```

Comment: @Joice: "thnks" is best expressed as a green tick to the left of the answer.